# How to properly show/hide mobile menu onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tailwind-css

I have this html to display a menu and also the mobile version of the menu. However the mobile version is not working properly. Do you know what is necessary to only show the menu svg icon first with the mobile menu hidden and then on the button to open the menu click show the mobile menu and the close svg icon?

As it is on the mobile version the menu already appears open with the button to close but the button dont hide the menu.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2vjo0gnc/

HTML

```
    <div class="relative bg-gray-50 overflow-hidden">
      <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <div class="relative z-10 pb-8 bg-gray-50 sm:pb-16 md:pb-20 lg:max-w-2xl lg:w-full lg:pb-28 xl:pb-32">


          <div class="relative pt-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <nav class="relative flex items-center justify-between sm:h-10 lg:justify-start" aria-label="Global">
              <div class="flex items-center flex-grow flex-shrink-0 lg:flex-grow-0">
                <div class="flex items-center justify-between w-full md:w-auto">
                  <div class="flex">
                   
                    <span class="text-xl text-3xl font-bold">logo</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center md:hidden">
                    <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                 
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="hidden md:block md:ml-10 mt-2 md:pr-4 md:space-x-8">

                <a id="aboutUs" href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Link 1</a>

                <a id="ourTeam" href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Link 2</a>


                <a id="blog" href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Link 3</a>

                <a href="#" class="contact font-medium">Link 4</a>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>

          <!--
              Mobile menu, show/hide based on menu open state.

              Entering: "duration-150 ease-out"
                From: "opacity-0 scale-95"
                To: "opacity-100 scale-100"
              Leaving: "duration-100 ease-in"
                From: "opacity-100 scale-100"
                To: "opacity-0 scale-95"
            -->
          <div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
            <div class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
              <div class="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="flex">
                 
                 
                  <span class="text-xl text-3xl font-bold text-gray-600">logo</span>
                </div>
                <div class="-mr-2">
                  <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    <span class="sr-only">Close main menu</span>
                    <!-- Heroicon name: outline/x -->
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                    <svg id="open-mobile-nav-btn"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 " viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                </svg>
                    
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">

                <a id="features" href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link 1</a>

                <a id="ourTeam" href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link 2</a>

                <a id="blog" href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link 3</a>

                <a href="#" class="contact block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link4</a>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>

          <main class="mt-10 mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:mt-12 sm:px-6 md:mt-16 lg:mt-20 lg:px-8 xl:mt-28">
            <div class="sm:text-center lg:text-left">
              <h1 class="text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-600 sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl">
                <span class="block xl:inline">Test</span>
                <span class="block xl:inline">title</span>
              </h1>

            </div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lg:absolute lg:inset-y-0 lg:right-0 lg:w-1/2">
        <img class="h-56 w-full object-cover sm:h-72 md:h-96 lg:w-full lg:h-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
    const nav = document.querySelector('#mobile-nav');
    const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-mobile-nav-btn');

    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('show/ hide the menu');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript to do that. Have a variable `isOpen` which checks if its open (`true`) or closed (`false`), control the navigation and button based on that.

Tailwind does not provide Javascript but provides comments in html what to use to get the desired effect of opening and closing.